# Exception *read access violation* How should I properly delete array of lists of pointers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

so I have this problem with my hashtable whenever i try to delete all elements from my hashtable and then after that again add new elements to it, there will pop some exception *read access violation* and its caused when i add new elements to hashtable, and am pretty sure cause am clearing it wrong.My clear method looks like that:

```
void clear()
{

    delete[] arr;
    arr = nullptr;
    maxSize = 256;
    currentSize = 0;

}
```

my hashtable class:

```
template<class T>
class hashTable {
private:
    unsigned int currentSize;
    unsigned int maxSize;



public:

    list<T>* arr;
    hashTable() {
        maxSize = 256;
        currentSize = 0;
        arr = new list<T>[maxSize];
    }
//some interface methods
```

my main:

```
hashTable<int>* table = new hashTable<int>();

const int MAX_ORDER = 6; 
for (int o = 1; o <= MAX_ORDER; o++)
{
    
    const int n = pow(10, o); 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)

    {

        //add element

    }
table->clear()
```

Much appreciate any help. (:

Reproducible Example :http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12d6d48bd423155b

Comment: Why not declare `arr` as `std::vector <std::list <T>>`?  Your problems are likely to go away then.

Comment: yes could've helpped most likely , but the thing is that I'm not really allowed to use STL libary. :D

Comment: In that case, you should post a [mre] so that people can see what the problem actually is.

Comment: `clear` sets `arr` to `nullptr`. Presumably, whatever function you call next expects `arr` not to be `nullptr`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12d6d48bd423155b provided code sample that causes the problem to understand better the problem, when i commented line with nullptr didnt change much.

Comment: In `clear` you delete `arr`. Then you try to access `arr` again afterwards in `addNewElement`. That is a big problem. Either don't delete `arr` in `clear` or check if you have to recreate `arr` again with new in `addNewElement`

Comment: oh yeah xD it was pretty logic now it works smoothly, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed clear() into this :

```
void clear()
{

    delete[] this->arr;
    this->maxSize = 256;
    this->arr = new list<T>[maxSize]();
    this->currentSize = 0;

}
```

now is way faster and no exceptions thank you all for feedback.